# How to search, assign and print objects from a "child" Class/Table - (Parse.com + Appcelerator)

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, parse-platform

Would love some help with this. I've been trying many different ways and have just found this approach to be really complex and think it may be simpler, as I dont have a solution that works yet. I've asked the Parse.com community but have had not responses yet.

My datastore (parse.com) has two Classes/tables. Food Type and Food Items. A one-to-many relationship exists between Food Type and Food Items. For example, Produce is an Attribute (of the object "name") in the Class Food Type and it has many Food Items related to it (such as apples, bananas, lettuce, etc). This has been structured correctly in the datastore.

In the datastore, Food Type has three objects - colour, foodItemId (relation) and name. Name refers to the name of the food type, e.g. Produce, Colour is just a colour I've assigned to the name and foodItemId, when clicking on the relationship, I've added a bunch of fruits at the moment for testing.

The Food Item Class has four objects/elements - expiry, keyworkType (refers to whether its a Fruit, Veggie or other), name and photo. These are pretty self explanatory.

What I want to do is when the user wants to add an item to their inventory, they select the food type (e.g. produce) > it takes them to a page that would print out all the food items for that food type (e.g. the query would retrieve all food items that belonged to a specific food type).

**So what I am actually trying to do is match a Food Type - "Name" to the one a user enters (in this case it is Produce) > Then retrieve all Food Items that belong to that Food Type. So I want to retrieve the all Food Item objects that are "child" to a Food Type > Then be able to manipulate and play around with whatever I want with the returned Food Items.**

In short, everything I've tried isn't working and I would love some help.

Thanks Guys,

Gere

Answer (score 0):

check that... I Thought I had found the answer and it turned out to be wrong. I have since found the answer (this is the code you would need - this reference helped!!! https://www.parse.com/questions/can-i-use-include-in-a-query-to-include-all-members-of-a-parserelation-error-102 as well as https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Relation.html):

```
//create an array that will hold all the unique KeywordsTypes in it.
// This will be sent to another method to print out items that are in a KeywordType.
var keyword_type_array = new Array();

//get the info out of the db and then set it in the variables
var FoodType = Parse.Object.extend("Food_Type");
var FoodItem = Parse.Object.extend("Food_Item");    

//we want to find the Food Items that belong to a Food Type.
var query = new Parse.Query(FoodType);  

// so make it so the inner query actually says find the matching food type
query.equalTo("name", food_type);
query.first({
    success: function(results) {
        // get the results (object) and put them in a variable which will be used with relation
        var innerQuery = results;
        //make it a relational query.. aka.. find for the Food Type returned, the foodItemId and all that are in that corrospond to that field.
        var relation = innerQuery.relation("foodItemId"); //https://www.parse.com/questions/can-i-use-include-in-a-query-to-include-all-members-of-a-parserelation-error-102
        //run the relational query.
        relation.query().find({
            success: function(theFoodItems) {
                for (var i = 0; i < theFoodItems.length; i++) {             
                    //add all keywordTypes to the keyword type array. We will go through and get unique types out.
                    keyword_type_array[i] = theFoodItems[i].get("keywordType");                             
                }

                // create a new array that will hold all unique keyword types.
                var unique_keywords = new Array();

                // get unique keywords types.
                for (var i = 0; i < keyword_type_array.length; i++) {
                    var unique = true;

                    for (var j = 0; j < unique_keywords.length; j++) {
                        if (keyword_type_array[i] == unique_keywords[j]) {
                            unique = false;
                            break;
                        }                   
                    }

                    if (unique) {
                        // if a keyword is found to be unique.. put that keyword in the array.
                        unique_keywords.push(keyword_type_array[i]);                    
                    }
                }

                // So now we know what we need to print, lets call a function to print them.
                print_view_sections(unique_keywords);

            },
            error: function(object, error) {
                // The object was not retrieved successfully.
                // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
                alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message)
            }
        });
    },
    error: function(object, error) {
        // The object was not retrieved successfully.
        // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message)
    }
});
```